# JQuery Validation <select> min depends on other field, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a select "ArrearsLHOLocation" that has an option "None Selected" with a value of -1 and all other selectable values are greater than 0.

Here is the rule defined in my javascript

```
    $("#ArrearsLHOLocation").rules("add", {
        min: {
            depends: function (elem) {
                return $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked") ? 0 : -1;
            }
        },
        messages: {
            min: "You have stated that the applicant/coapplicant have LHO arrears but you have not stated where!"
        }
    });
```

Here are the watches as observed in Chrome.

```
 $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked") ? 0 : -1: 0
 $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked"): true
 $("#ArrearsLHOLocation").val(): "-1"
 $("#ArrearsLHOLocation").val() >=($("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked") ? 0 : -1): false
```

This page successfully submits, incorrectly.  If I toggle the radio button and the watches appear like this:

```
 $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked") ? 0 : -1: -1
 $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked"): false
 $("#ArrearsLHOLocation").val(): "-1"
 $("#ArrearsLHOLocation").val() >=($("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked") ? 0 : -1): true
```

This page is stopped from being submitted and my error message is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Steve

--Snippet of HTML as requested--

```
<td>Do they have arrears?</td><td>
Yes <input id="rbArrearsLHO" name="rbArrearsLHO" type="radio" value="True" />
No <input checked="checked" id="rbArrearsLHO" name="rbArrearsLHO" type="radio" value="False" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
   <blockquote>
    If YES, Where? 
       <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ArrearsLHOLocation must be a number." id="ArrearsLHOLocation" name="ArrearsLHOLocation">
            <option value="-1">None Selected</option>
            <option value="4">Location 1</option>
            <option value="6">Location 2</option>
            <option value="5">Location 3</option>
            <option value="7">Location 4</option>
       </select>
   </blockquote>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at jquery.validate I found that depends should only ever evaluate to true/false.  So modifying the min to have [param : 0] which would have been the min when I needed it.  Then changing the depends to evaluate to true when the minimum should be in effect solved this issue.

```
$("#ArrearsLHOLocation").rules("add", {
        min: {
            param: 0,
            depends: function (elem) {
                return $("#rbArrearsLHO[value='True']").is(":checked");
            }
        },
        messages: {
            min: "You have stated that the applicant/coapplicant have LHO arrears but you have not stated where!"
        }
    });
```

**DEMO**: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jyroofu9/1/) (forked from @Sparky's previous fiddle)

Comment: I'm still not sure why you insist on `min` for this... using it to force a choice on a `select` is very unusual.

Answer (score 1):

A `select` can only be `required` or not.  I've never seen the `min` rule used on a `select` to force the user to choose an option.

Your `"None Selected"` option should contain `value=""` and then when you declare the `required` rule on this, the user will be forced to select any option other than `"None Selected"`.

```
<select name="list">
    <option value="">None Selected</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Then your depends parameter would simply need to return a boolean to state whether the user needs to select an option.

```
$('[name="list"]').rules("add", {
    required: {
        depends: function (elem) {
            return $("#check").is(":checked");
        }
    },
    messages: {
        required: "Select from the list"
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7k2zg7rv/**

---

**EDIT:**

Since you want to keep your first `option` as `value="-1"`, you'll need to create a custom rule/method using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) that recognizes your first `option` as invalid.

```
$.validator.addMethod('select', function(value, element) {
    return (value == -1) ? false : true;
});
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7k2zg7rv/2/**

Comment: I would like to use 'min' if at all possible in this case to avoid making multitudes of changes to my mvc controllers and models.

Comment: @Steve, that's not how `min` works. If you insist on keeping the `value="-1"`, then you'd have to create a custom method.  See my edits.  http://jsfiddle.net/7k2zg7rv/2/

Comment: your most recent edit gave me an idea and it works! I will add it shortly to this question.  In short I add param: 0 to the "min" definition, and then adjust the depends to only evaluate true/false, which is what the validation function expects (only true/false)